# Reducing the number of a function's parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have some functions in my program that contain 15 or more parameters. However, all fifteen parameters are never needed at the same time.

I have some switch statement functions, using dictionaries, to execute the relevant function needed. My most extreme example can be seen below:

```
def Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, raw_data_LP, maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min,
                            Measurement_Max, Measurement_Type, SG, Tank_Shape, area, dish,
                            diameter, length, Strapping_Table, Poly_Data, Tank_Number,
                            LevelOffset):
    switcher = {
        '8AI': lambda: inst.FourTwenty(raw_data_LP, maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min,
                                       Measurement_Max, Measurement_Type, SG, Tank_Shape,
                                       area, dish, diameter, length, Strapping_Table,
                                       Poly_Data, Tank_Number, LevelOffset),
        'Magprobe': lambda: inst.SGMagprobe(raw_data_LP,
                                            Tank_Shape, area, dish, diameter, length,
                                            Strapping_Table, Poly_Data, Tank_Number,
                                            LevelOffset),
        'TLS': lambda: inst.TLS(raw_data_LP),
    }
    return switcher.get(InstType_C, lambda : None)()
```

Now I have tried looking into `*args` and `**kwargs` but I am unsure if these will help me. If I use `*args` to define the function, I will still need to define all the arguments when calling the function. However, I would then need three different function calls in `if: elif:` statements to declare the right amount of arguments. ie:

```
if type == '8AI':
    volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, raw_data_LP, maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min,
                                     Measurement_Max, Measurement_Type, SG, Tank_Shape, area,
                                     dish, diameter, length, Strapping_Table, Poly_Data,
                                     Tank_Number, LevelOffset)
elif type == 'Magprobe':
    volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, raw_data_LP, SG, Tank_Shape, area, dish,
                                     diameter, length, Strapping_Table, Poly_Data,
                                     Tank_Number, LevelOffset)
elif type == 'TLS':
    volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, raw_data_LP)
```

Obviously, this just defeats the point of the switch statements and won't solve the problem with the really long function calls.

Overall, it does not cause any problems with my code, but if there is a better way of implementing it, I would like to learn how.

Comment: Have you tried using default parameters? `def Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, raw_data_LP=None, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You could make the switching function accept all but it first argument, `InstType_C`, keyword arguments. This will make it possible to specify what values you want to pass in each call to it.

To illustrate this, I've applied it to your example code. To make something that was actually runnable, a number of things that are left out of your code have been added, but only for testing purposes.

This may make it look like it's not much of an improvement, but that's because for testing a bunch of variables are defined which contain their own name. This makes the calls to the switcher function longer because each keyword argument is assigned the value of a variable of the same name, so they're something like twice a long as they would be in real practice.

All the testing code makes this look very long and complex, but I hope you can ignore it enough to understand the advantages of what is being purposed.

The fact that you aren't following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions also makes things look "busy" because it messes-up the syntax-highlighting SO applies to code shown.

```
# For testing define and create a class with methods to call.
# Each method will just print out the values of the arguments it was passed.
class Inst(object):
    def FourTwenty(self, *args):
        print('called FourTwenty({})\n'.format(args))
    def SGMagprobe(self, *args):
        print('called SGMagprobe({})\n'.format(args))
    def TLS(self, *args):
        print('called TLS({})\n'.format(args))

inst = Inst()  # create instance for testing

# For testing create variables to pass as arguments, each variable will contain
# the variable's name as its value. i.e. some_variable = 'some_variable'.
arguments = [arg.strip() for arg in (
    "raw_data_LP, maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min, Measurement_Max, "
    "Measurement_Type, SG, Tank_Shape, area, dish, diameter, length, "
    "Strapping_Table, Poly_Data, Tank_Number, LevelOffset").split(',')]
for arg in arguments:
    globals()[arg] = arg

#### End of testing scaffold.

class AttrDict(dict):
    """Allows use of dot notation to access dictionary's contents."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

def Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, **kwargs):
    kwargs = AttrDict(kwargs)  # make them easier to access

    switcher = {
        '8AI': lambda: inst.FourTwenty(kwargs.raw_data_LP, kwargs.maxcounts_C,
                                       kwargs.Measurement_Min,
                                       kwargs.Measurement_Max, kwargs.Measurement_Type,
                                       kwargs.SG, kwargs.Tank_Shape, kwargs.area, kwargs.dish,
                                       kwargs.diameter, kwargs.length, kwargs.Strapping_Table,
                                       kwargs.Poly_Data, kwargs.Tank_Number, kwargs.LevelOffset),
        'Magprobe': lambda: inst.SGMagprobe(kwargs.raw_data_LP, kwargs.Tank_Shape, kwargs.area,
                                            kwargs.dish, kwargs.diameter, kwargs.length,
                                            kwargs.Strapping_Table, kwargs.Poly_Data,
                                            kwargs.Tank_Number, kwargs.LevelOffset),
        'TLS': lambda: inst.TLS(kwargs.raw_data_LP),
    }
    return switcher.get(InstType_C, lambda: None)()

volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C('8AI', raw_data_LP=raw_data_LP,
                                 maxcounts_C=maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min=Measurement_Min,
                                 Measurement_Max=Measurement_Max,
                                 Measurement_Type=Measurement_Type, SG=SG,
                                 Tank_Shape=Tank_Shape, area=area, dish=dish,
                                 diameter=diameter, length=length,
                                 Strapping_Table=Strapping_Table, Poly_Data=Poly_Data,
                                 Tank_Number=Tank_Number, LevelOffset=LevelOffset)
volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C('Magprobe', raw_data_LP=raw_data_LP, SG=SG,
                                 Tank_Shape=Tank_Shape, area=area, dish=dish,
                                 diameter=diameter, length=length,
                                 Strapping_Table=Strapping_Table, Poly_Data=Poly_Data,
                                 Tank_Number=Tank_Number, LevelOffset=LevelOffset)
volume = Instrument_Type_Calcs_C('TLS', raw_data_LP=raw_data_LP)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default parameters and named parameters to solve your problem.

But if you need functions with that much parameters, I'd say you probably can make your program more object oriented.

Make a class, an instance of which has the `__call__` operator (or just a method) featuring the parameters you mostly use.

And give it other methods to control settings that don't often change.

Answer (score 0):

Either use default parameters (as has been pointed out in the comments, i.e. `def func(a, optional=None, optional2=None ...):` or you could also do this:

```
def Instrument_Type_Calcs_C(InstType_C, **kwargs):
    # You can also simply added a proper list of strings, I was merely to lazy to write on up
    allowed_kwargs = ('raw_data_LP, maxcounts_C, Measurement_Min,
                                 Measurement_Max, Measurement_Type, SG, Tank_Shape, area,
                                 dish, diameter, length, Strapping_Table, Poly_Data,
                                 Tank_Number, LevelOffset').strip(' ').split(',')
    wrong_kwargs = [k for in kwargs if k not in allowed_kwargs]
    if wrong_kwargs:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Kwarg passed! %s" wrong_kwargs)

    # rest of your code
    ...
```

`kwargs` is adict of all named parameters packed into a dict, so you can access it within your function just like you would access a dictionary.

But as has been pointed out, you should perhaps consider `oop`ing your code. The above solutions simply cleans up the function header, and not the readability of the function, nor achieves better simplicity.

Btw, you can also use the starred expressions (`**` and `*`) within your function - they essentially unpack a list (`*`) or a dict (`**`). That's useful in, for example, list comprehensions or when unpacking to other variables:

```
l = ['hello', 1, 2] 
s, *nums = *l

s  # 'hello' 

nums  # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a dictionary "parameter" like argument, in which put all the parameters you need. Something like this:

```
def FoobarFunction(parameters):
    if parameters["KnownParameter"] == ... :
        # Do Something
        ...
```

Comment: you can achieve this with defining `**kwargs` as a parameter instead.

Comment: Yes, is another way of doing it. Bu a dictionary is clearer.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Not just that it's unpythonic, you also need to initialize a dictionary first. Using kwargs avoids this.